# calculate percentage of occurrences in column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column with thousands of rows. I want to select the top significant one. Let's say I want to select all the rows that would represent 90% of my sample. How would I do that?

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, one for product_id one showing whether it was purchased or not (value is or 0 or 1)

```
product_id    purchased
   a             1
   b             0
   c             0
   d             1
   a             1
   .             .
   .             .
```

with df['product_id'].value_counts() I can have all my product-ids ranked by number of occurrences.
Let's say now I want to get the number of product_ids that I should consider in my future analysis that would represent 90% of the total of occurences.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you only want to consider rows corresponding to products that were actually purchased?

Answer (score 0):

If want all `product_id` with counts under `0.9` then use:

```
s = df['product_id'].value_counts(normalize=True).cumsum()
df1 = df[df['product_id'].isin(s.index[s < 0.9])]
```

Or if want all rows sorted by counts and get `90%` of them:

```
s1 = df['product_id'].map(df['product_id'].value_counts()).sort_values(ascending=False)

df2 = df.loc[s1.index[:int(len(df) * 0.9)]]
```